# Select row without substring

Tags: java, regex, wikipedia

I'm trying to select just names from text like this (Slovak dump of Wikipedia):

```
    |Meno = Hans Joachim
|Plné meno = Aristoteles (???????????)
|Plné meno = Francis Bacon
|Plné meno = Sokrates ({{Cudzojazyčne|grc|????????|pc=n}})
|Meno            = Svätý František z Assisi <br /> ''(Giovanni Battista Bernardone)''
  |Meno = Friedrich Ludwig Gottlob Frege
   |Meno             = Adam František Kollár (Kolárik)
|meno    = [[J. Edgar Hoover|John Edgar Hoover]]
|meno    = [[Benedikt XIV. (1740 – 1758)|Benedikt XIV.]]
|meno    = [[Milan Rastislav Štefánik|Milan Rastislav Štefánik]]
   |Meno             = '''Ján Filc'''
  |Meno = Jean le Rond d'Alembert
```

Output should be like:

```
Hans Joachim
Aristoteles
Francis Bacon
Sokrates
Svätý František z Assisi
Friedrich Ludwig Gottlob Frege
Adam František Kollár (Kolárik)
J. Edgar Hoover|John Edgar Hoover
Benedikt XIV. (1740 – 1758)|Benedikt XIV.
Milan Rastislav Štefánik|Milan Rastislav Štefánik
Ján Filc
Jean le Rond d'Alembert
```

When the name is written correctly, this regular expression is working fine: `= *(.*?)$`
But when there are thing like "(???????????)", HTML tags and something between "{{" and "}}", I cannot select the name without the unwanted substring.

I tried a lot of options on [this regex tester page (http://regex101.com/r/gS8iQ9/1)](http://regex101.com/r/gS8iQ9/1), but none of them worked.

In Java code I'm using

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("= *(.*?)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
   String foundSubstring = matcher.group(1);
   ...
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions on how select text after "=" but without question marks, HTML code and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex was almost right, but your input is a bit trick to work with, and you can do it in one line:

```
String name = line.replaceAll(".*?=[\\[ ']*([\\p{L}0-9|'. ()–]+[\\p{L}.)]).*", "$1");
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/lT9YfiySXT)

I have tested this and it produced your desired output given your sample input.

Comment: ♦ This is my output after I tried this code (text after "new:" is output)

`|Plné meno = Aristoteles (???????????) new: Aristoteles (?


|Meno            = Svätý Augustín new: Svä` this leave some of the unwanted characters and also doesn't work with our special characters like 'ä' But thanks, I will try to teach from this

Comment: @Tunerx I think I've fixed it. It was a bit tricky - has to use the posix class `\p{L}` for "letter". Try the latest version. (I can't test it now - thumbing code on iPhone)

Comment: it's weird, in demo I can see it's working, but in Java it has different output. For example `|Plné meno = Sokrates ({{Cudzojazyčne|grc|????????|pc=n}}) new: Sokrates (` is (despite '(') working, but this is not `|Plné meno = Aristoteles (???????????) new: Aristoteles (???????????)`. Also the `Benedict` is OK... I'm not really sure by now it is possible to catch all the problems in one regex (for example `Jan Filc` isn't working either). Also wikipedia has much more problematic lines that I didn't catch yet... But thanks, now I know how to approach this problem.

Comment: @Tunerx I am at a computer now where I can test it, and the latest version works. If you have other edge cases that don't work, post them in your question, let me know, and I'll have a look.

Comment: inside all testers (I'm using http://regex101.com/r/gS8iQ9/2 ) it's working great. In Java is everything working, except the line with question marks inside brackets... There is a lot of lines where this doesn't work `|Plné meno = Anaxagoras (??????????) new: Anaxagoras (??????????)
|Plné meno = Anaximandros (????????????) new: Anaximandros (????????????)
|Plné meno = Anaximenes (??????????) new: Anaximenes (??????????)`. I really don't get it, the input is the same as is in the testers :(

Comment: there could not be problems with java code? But I tried it exactly as you posted it... `String foundSubstring = line.replaceAll(".*?=[\\[ ']*([\\p{L}0-9|'. ()–]+[\\p{L}.)]).*", "$1");
System.out.println(line + " new: " + foundSubstring);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=[\\s\\p{Punct}]*(.*?)\\p{Punct}*$");
```

`\p{Punct}` stands for punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

Comment: Thanks, this works great on line like `|meno    = [[Benedikt XIV. (1740 – 1758)|Benedikt XIV.]] new: Benedikt XIV. (1740 – 1758)|Benedikt XIV`. But this doesn't apply to lines like `|Plné meno = Sokrates ({{Cudzojazyčne|grc|????????|pc=n}}) new: Sokrates ({{Cudzojazyčne|grc|????????|pc=n` or `|Plné meno = Aristoteles (???????????) new: Aristoteles (???????????`. Output is always after "new: ".